# Просвечивание объектов светом

Tags: opengl, освещение

Есть сцена. В центре (0, 0, 0) находится источник света. Вокруг него вращается объект. Проблема - когда объект находится между источником света и наблюдателем, этот объект просвечивается насквозь. Как бы убрать такой эффект?

Отрисовка

```delphi
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  CLight: array [0..3] of GLfloat = (0, 0, 0, 1);
begin
  glPushMatrix;
  try
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.1, 20, 20);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, @CLight);
    glTranslatef(0.9, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.3, 20, 20);
  finally
    glPopMatrix;
  end;
  Win32Check(SwapBuffers(FDC));
end;
```

Инициализация

```delphi
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LFmt: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
  LIdx: Integer;
begin
  FDC := GetDC(Handle);
  FillChar(LFmt, SizeOf(LFmt), 0);
  LFmt.nSize := SizeOf(LFmt);
  LFmt.nVersion := 1;
  LFmt.dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  LFmt.iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  LFmt.cColorBits := 24;

  LIdx := Win32Check(ChoosePixelFormat(FDC, @LFmt));
  Win32Check(SetPixelFormat(FDC, LIdx, @LFmt));
  FGLCtx := Win32Check(wglCreateContext(FDC));
  Win32Check(wglMakeCurrent(FDC, FGLCtx));

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
end;
```

Вот скриншот того, что происходит при вращении сцены

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чего я не добавил?

Comment: Как вы вращаете сцены?

Comment: @Unick Перед отрисовкой вызываю `glRotatef()`

Comment: Тип источника света? Привидете пожалуйста весь код.

Comment: @Unick Весь код приведен. Никаких дополнительных параметров не устанавливается. На нажатие клавиш вызывается `glRotatef()`

Comment: Возможно часть сферы режиться ближней отсекующей плоскостью или проблемы с нормалями. Но т.к. вы используете не новый OpenGL (с шейдерами), то мне сложно дать совет как можно понять что едёт не так. Попробуйте добавить много сфер или других обеъектов с разными позициями и посмотреть на каких свет работает не верно.

Comment: @Unick Хм. Идея с отсекающей плоскостью мне нравится. Спасибо. Проверю

Comment: @Unick Вы были абсолютно правы, сфера резалась ближней плоскостью. Я переносил центр координат на 0.9, а потом рисовал сферу радиусом 0.3. `glFrustrum` я с наскока не осилил, потому просто сделал перенос координат на 0.7 и все заработало. Напишите ответ для потомков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в относительном расположении объекта и камеры. При сближении сферы с камерой ближняя часть отсекалась ближней отсекущюей плоскостью камеры. В результате мы видели ближнюю к источнику света часть сферы, которая действительно освещена.

Подробнее про это можно прочитать в статье: http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehex2.htm

ПС. Видимо функция glutSolidSphere задаёт также внутрению стенку сферы, т.к. если бы сфера имела только внешную стенку, то она должна была просвечивать. Также видимо нормали внутреней стенки сферы направлены в ту же сторону, что и внешней, т.к. если бы это было не так: то внутреняя часть сферы должна была быть тоже тёмной.